# Windows 10, two monitor setup, second monitor turned off but Windows still works as if it's on?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop

Bought a second monitor today, plugged it in, turned my old monitor into portrait.
I don't plan on using this second monitor a lot, only when reading some longer stuff, so I turned it off (with the power button, not sleep or anything like that).
Problem: Windows still allows me to drag my cursor and any app windows to this second monitor. Super annoying, because I can't reliably use the top right window close button or bottom right hot corner anymore, among other things.

I read somewhere that it might be a bad/non VESA-certified DP cable (both monitors plugged in via DP, one came with the new monitor, the other is third party), so I switched cables, and the old one worked as usual with the new cable, but the new monitor started turning on and off every few seconds; could be because it's a 240hz monitor, or, perhaps, this is a clear indicator of a bad cable?

TL;DR - I want my second monitor to not be detected when I turn it off via its power button. Wat do?

OS: Windows 10

Hardware: MSI RTX 2070 GAMING Z 8G, BenQ BL2411 (old monitor), Gigabyte M27Q X (new monitor).

Comment: Try hitting Windows key and P together to bring up projection settings, and click "First screen only" (not sure if that's the exact text)

Comment: @Arandomcoder that works, but it is not an automatic solution, I'm looking for something that would do this automatically. Just seamlessly turn off the second display in the OS like it, IMO, should have done already. And preferably without turning the main screen off and on again for no apparent reason.